# Zend Framework 2 AbstractRestfulController - Exceptions as JSON

Tags: php, zend-framework2

My goal is get a JSON like

```json
{ 
  "meta": { 
    "error_type": "error type", 
    "code": 400, 
    "error_message": "error msg" 
  } 
}
```

In case something went wrong.
I tried to put the try catch block both in the rest controller's action and in the model but I get the whole exception stack (I mean with the layout + view)

What's the right way ?

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception in the controller action.

Return a JsonModel from the action containing exception information:

```
public function someAction()
{
    try {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return new JsonModel(array(
            'meta' => array(
                'code'          => $e->getCode(),
                'error_message' => $e->getMessage(),
                //...
            )
        ));
    }
    //...
}
```

Source: [Returning JSON from a ZF2 controller action](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/returning-json-from-a-zf2-controller-action/)

Answer (score 0):

> [I tried to put the try catch block both in the action rest
>   controller]

I've just tried like
(I want my goal become true but
when only if something goes wrong :) )

```
public function create($data) 
{ 
        try{ 
    $artist = $this->getRequest()->getPost('artist', null); 
        $title = $this->getRequest()->getPost('title', null); 
        $album = new Album(); 
        $album->exchangeArray(array('artist'=>$artist,'title'=>$title)); 
        $id = $this->getAlbumTable()->saveAlbum($album); 
        return $this->get($id);   
     } 
     catch (Exception $e) { 
      return new JsonModel(array( 
                'meta' =>array( 
                    'code'=>500, 
                    'error-num'=>$e->getCode(), 
                    'error-msg'=>$e->getMessage(), 
                ) 
            )); 
        } 

 }
```

but as above it doesn't work
instead of json data i get the 
whole default exception stack with layout.

Comment: Can you paste the exception trace in a gist? This doesn't look normal, and in my opinion, the exception is raised outside of the `try-catch` block.

Comment: to trigger exception I set the artist album field as unique than $ curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "artist=AC DC2&title=Dirty Deeds2" http://localhost/zf2/public/rest twice you can look at the whole stack http://pastebin.com/uLftaG7s

Comment: Are you able to "Stop" it by putting a `die('here');` halt in the catch block?

Comment: public function create($data)
{try{}catch (Exception $e) {exit('here');}}
it's the same I get the whole exception stack

Comment: Which basically means your `create` is not part of the affected code. You probably want to be step-by-step debugging here.

Comment: Any solution to this?